# How can I parse a pairwise data file with relations like (A-1, A-2, A-3, B-2, B-4, B-5, etc) to a dictionary-like structure in R

Tags: r, list, dictionary, parsing, hashmap

I'm a ruby developer but I need to develop some part of my final work degree in R. I am reading a file like this:

```
genes = read.delim(opt$pregeneset)
```

whose content is like:

```
              GVR    ENTREZ
1   chr15.gvr7.17    114791
2   chr15.gvr7.17    283767
3   chr15.gvr7.17 100996331
4   chr15.gvr7.17    390538
5   chr15.gvr7.17    283694
6   chr15.gvr8.16    123606
7   chr15.gvr8.16     81614
8   chr15.gvr8.16     23191
9   chr15.gvr9.15    283685
10  chr15.gvr9.15      7681
```

And I would like to transform this data in some sort of dictionary structure like this:

```
gvr_data = {"chr15.gvr7.17": [114791, 283767, 100996331, 390538, 283694],
 "chr15.gvr8.16": [123606, 81614, 23191], 
 "chr15.gvr9.15": [283685, 7681]}
```

and so on. Usually I would iterate on GVR saving the "i" item as the key and the same "i" item in ENTREZ pushed in an array as the value for generating the dictionary/hash map showed before, but I don't know how to do that in R.

Comment: Try `split(genes, genes$GVR)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a *named list*, and you can get it like this:

```r
result <- lapply(split.data.frame(genes, genes$GVR), function(x) x$ENTREZ)
print(result)
#> $`chr15.gvr7.17`
#> [1]    114791    283767 100996331    390538    283694
#> 
#> $chr15.gvr8.16
#> [1] 123606  81614  23191
#> 
#> $chr15.gvr9.15
#> [1] 283685   7681
```

Now you can use the `$` operator to access any single vector like this:

```r
result$chr15.gvr9.15
#> [1] 283685   7681
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That really worked for me because I needed to store it in a way I could loop through later to apply a function to every vector.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two types of output with base R, maybe one of them is what you want

- Solution 1: output as data frame

```
gvr_data_df  <- aggregate(ENTREZ~GVR, genes, FUN = function(x) x)

> gvr_data_df
            GVR                                    ENTREZ
1 chr15.gvr7.17 114791, 283767, 100996331, 390538, 283694
2 chr15.gvr8.16                      123606, 81614, 23191
3 chr15.gvr9.15                              283685, 7681
```

- Solution 2: output as list

```
gvr_data_lst <- lapply(split(genes,genes$GVR),`[[`,2)

> gvr_data_lst
$chr15.gvr7.17
[1]    114791    283767 100996331    390538    283694

$chr15.gvr8.16
[1] 123606  81614  23191

$chr15.gvr9.15
[1] 283685   7681
```

Answer (score 0):

There already is an accepted answer but here is another one, maybe more like the posted expected result.

```
aggregate(ENTREZ ~ GVR, genes, function(x){
  x <- paste(x, collapse = ', ')
  paste0('[', x, ']')
})
#            GVR                                      ENTREZ
#1 chr15.gvr7.17 [114791, 283767, 100996331, 390538, 283694]
#2 chr15.gvr8.16                      [123606, 81614, 23191]
#3 chr15.gvr9.15                              [283685, 7681]
```

Or in JSON format.

```
agg <- aggregate(ENTREZ ~ GVR, genes, paste)
jsonlite::toJSON(agg, "values", pretty = TRUE)
#[
#  ["chr15.gvr7.17", ["114791", "283767", "100996331", "390538", "283694"]],
#  ["chr15.gvr8.16", ["123606", "81614", "23191"]],
#  ["chr15.gvr9.15", ["283685", "7681"]]
#]
```

**Data.**

```
genes <- read.table(text = "
              GVR    ENTREZ
1   chr15.gvr7.17    114791
2   chr15.gvr7.17    283767
3   chr15.gvr7.17 100996331
4   chr15.gvr7.17    390538
5   chr15.gvr7.17    283694
6   chr15.gvr8.16    123606
7   chr15.gvr8.16     81614
8   chr15.gvr8.16     23191
9   chr15.gvr9.15    283685
10  chr15.gvr9.15      7681
", header = TRUE)
```